# Cómo soluciono el Error CS1061 al momento de ejecutar mi proyecto

Tags: c#, .net

Cuando ejecuto mi proyecto me sale el siguiente error:

> Mensaje de error del compilador: CS1061:
> 'LICL_SIMEBL.Cls_SUNAT_Factura_BL' does not contain a definition for
> 'ObtenerRespuestaZIPSunat_BL' and no extension method
> 'ObtenerRespuestaZIPSunat_BL' accepting a first argument of type
> 'LICL_SIMEBL.Cls_SUNAT_Factura_BL' could be found (are you missing a
> using directive or an assembly reference?)

Este es el metodo que trato de Llamar:

```
using LICL_SIMEDL;
namespace LICL_SIMEBL
{
    public class Cls_SUNAT_Factura_BL
    {
        Cls_Factura_SUNAT_DL ObjtDL = new Cls_Factura_SUNAT_DL();

        public string[] ObtenerRespuestaZIPSunat_BL(string ruta)
        {
            return ObjtDL.ObtenerRespuestaZIPSunat_DL(ruta);
        }
    }
{
```

Aqui lo estoy llamando:

```
private void EnviarDocumento (string Archivo)
{
  Cls_SUNAT_Factura_BL Respu = new Cls_SUNAT_Factura_BL();
  Archivo = "R - " + Archivo;
  string[] rz = Respu.ObtenerRespuestaZIPSunat_BL(archivo);
  foreach (var item in rz)
  {
     SIGAUtilitario.MensajeAlert(item, 3);
  }
}
```

No entiendo,ya que estoy creando una variable de tipo "Cls_SUNAT_Factura_BL" y estoy usandolo correctamente.

Comment: Revisa si necesitas una referencia a alguna DLL.

Comment: ¿Está todo en el mismo namespace? Si no es así, te faltaría una directiva using LICL_SIMEBL; en la clase desde la que haces la llamada.